# My Giphy API is not giving any output. Where is the error in the code?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json

I am learning Node.js and complete beginner to programming. I am trying to make Giphy API but its not giving any result. Kindly check my code and let me know the error.

```
  <h1>My Giphy</h1>
  <div id="gif-wrap">

  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.get("/", function(req, res){
   res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");

})

app.post("/", function(req, res){
    const apiKey = "35r4WFb9CgO46XVbZA7d03zAjfM4vU48";
    const endPoint = "random";
    const tagy = "burrito";
    const rate = "g";
    const url = "https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/"+ endPoint +"?api_key="+ apiKey +"&tag="+ tagy +"&rating="+ rate +"";

    var newGif = () => $.getJSON(giphyURL, json => renderGif(json.data));


    // Display Gif in gif wrap container
    var renderGif = _giphy => {
        console.log(_giphy);
        // Set gif as bg image
        $gif-wrap.css({
            "background-image": 'url("' + _giphy.images.original.url + '")'
        });

        // Start duration countdown
        // refreshRate();
    };
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server is running on Port 3000");
})
```

Comment: What is “$gif - wrap” supposed to be on the server side?